# Prawn table not creating in Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have the following table code:

> member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments = [["14169021-00",
>   "Chris", 9, "YMCA in the Tampa, FL area is fantastic.  I would like to
>   see the level of support for other sports also provided to
>   racquetball."], ["1660592-00", "Nayrone", 9, "There are so many
>   offerings for activities and there are many convenient locations
>   throughout the area."], ["16183029-00", "Mary", 9, "I like the staff
>   but the showers are gross"], ["16257833-00", "Phyllis", 10, "A
>   comfortable environment, a place where you can meet people and most
>   importantly the staff is always available."], ["1629846-00", "Joan",
>   10, "Cost, Distance , Family Friendly"], ["16204559-00", "Lisa-Marie",
>   5, "The facilities are fairly crowded which makes working out on
>   equipment or participating in classes cramped and difficult.  "],
>   ["16258576-00", "Michael", 7, "yhe cost way to much\r\n"],
>   ["16161644-00", "April", 10, ""], ["1663157-00", "Mariela", 10, "Great
>   customer service, clean facilities and professional staff "],
>   ["16114120-00", "Alison", 10, "The Y offers great programs and is
>   active in the local community. "], ["16177159-00", "Sheri", 10, "The Y
>   is a place for everything. It is a place for fitness, fellowship,
>   socialization, community, upward progretion of the youth, employment
>   opps..."]]

```
table([
        ["Member ID", "First Name", "NPS Score", "Comments"],
        [member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments]
          .transpose.reject{ |x| x[2].nil? }
      ], 
      :position => :center, :column_widths => {0 => 50, 1 => 60, 2 => 45, 3 => 285}) do
        row(0).style :background_color => 'C0C0C0'
      end
```

The table is generating with only the header row (`Member ID, First Name, etc.`). The actual `member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments` array is not populating in the column.

Any thoughts as to why this is?

Comment: `member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments` - it's probably the longest variable name I've seen so far.

Comment: Could you explain what youa re trying to do with: `[member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments]
          .transpose.reject{ |x| x[2].nil? }` - this is almost certainly not right. Do you want to display all the data where nps score is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
table([
    ["Member ID", "First Name", "NPS Score", "Comments"],
    *member_id_and_first_name_and_nps_score_and_comments.reject{ |x| x[2].nil? }
  ], 
  :position => :center, :column_widths => {0 => 50, 1 => 60, 2 => 45, 3 => 285}) do
    row(0).style :background_color => 'C0C0C0'
  end
```

Comment: That does it, the splat operator and transpose was off. Thanks.